# nVLC crashing with integrated camera

Tags: c#, .net, vlc, libvlc

I am using nVLC wrapper in C# for streaming using a windows 7 (64-bit laptop) with integrated camera and VS2013/.net 4.0. When I use a USB webcam plugged into my windows 7 laptop everything works fine. When I use the integrated camera which comes with the laptop I see a crash with an unhandled exception. Here are the details of the crash

```
    Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 77704273
    Faulting application name: MyStreamer_nVLC.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54340652
    Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18247, time stamp: 0x521ea8e7
    Exception code: 0xc0000005
    Fault offset: 0x00034273
    Faulting process id: 0x2b68
    Faulting application start time: 0x01cfe24badf6a829
    Faulting application path: C:\Users\DarkOne\Desktop\Debug\MyStreamer_nVLC.exe
    Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
    Report Id: 014bdbd1-4e3f-11e4-830a-a240181b5488
```

Here's the code that is causing the crash. The integrated camera turns on, I see the green light followed immediately by a crash. USB camera works fine.

```
    string videoDevice = "Integrated Camera"
    string videoDeviceOption = "dshow-vdev=" + videoDevice ;
    string output = @":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=256,fps=30,scale=1,acodec=none}:udp{nux=ts,dst=127.0.0.1:8080} ";
    media = factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(@"dshow://", videoDeviceOption, output);
    player = factory.CreatePlayer<IVideoPlayer>();
    player.Open(media);
    player.Play();
```